# How to use shell glob as what * does in regular expression

Tags: shell, wildcards

I have some files named like: starting with "title." and ending with ".txt", and between them, there may be something else or maybe not. For example: `title.txt`, `title.abc.txt`, `title.123.txt`.

Now I want to copy all of them to another folder. How can I use one `cp` command to copy all the files?

Using regular expression, this can be done as:

```
ls | egrep 'title(\..*)*\.txt' | xargs -I{} cp {} destination_folder/
```

But it's too complicated: you need help from `egrep` and `xargs`. Is there an easy way using shell's built-in function glob/wildcards to do the magic? Something like:

```
cp title[magic]txt destination_folder/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to match the specific same regex in basic globbing is to do:

```
cp title[.]txt title.*.txt destination_folder/
```

Assuming that the files exist (or set nullglob and then no file at all will generate a cp error).

Or:

```
$ ksh -c '
      set -- ~(N)title[.]txt ~(N)title.*.txt
      [ $# -ge 1 ] && cp "$@" dir/
  '
```

Or:

```
$ bash -O nullglob -c '
    set -- title[.]txt title.*.txt
    [ $# -ge 1 ] && cp "$@" dir/
  '
```

Or similar in other shells.

---

## Why

Technically, there isn't any possible equivalent of a regex's `*` in a glob.

Mainly because a regex single `*` has no meaning. It gets meaning when there is something before it, and it then means repeat the previous token (the something) `0` or more times.

What has an exact equivalent is: a regex of `.*` is exactly equivalent to a glob of `*`.

The equivalent of a regex like `title(\..*)*\.txt` is near to `title.*.txt`.

### start and end

I assume the exact regex you should have written for grep is:

```
^title(\..*)*\.txt$
```

Which will comply with your statements of *starting with "title."* and *ending with ".txt"*. Starting should be signaled with `^` and ending should be signaled with `$` in a regex.

The start and end are included by default in a glob.

### dot

A dot, being an special character in a regex, should be escaped: `\.`.

A dot is not special in a glob and needs no escaping.

### optional character

But there is no way to express an optional character in a glob (basic).

A `(c|d)?`, which in a regex means: "an optional c or d", or, in simple words: a character `c` or `d` **zero or one time**, has no equivalent in basic glob. To get that, you need to use **extended** globbing. The syntax for an optional string is:

```
?(c|d)        # glob
```

So:

```
?(.*)         # zero or once `?( )` a dot followed by anything (`*`).
```

Means: optionally match a dot followed by anything (even empty).

And the whole glob would be:

```
title?(.*).txt            # only in extended globbing.
```

The way to set the extended globbing vary per shell (is not portable):

- `ksh  :                      on by default, no need to set anything.`
- `bash : shopt -s extglob`
- `zsh  : set -o extendedglob`

### portable (almost)

The only way to match the specific same regex in basic globbing is to do:

```
echo title[.]txt title.*.txt
```

### nullglob

But all the above matching is assuming some match will result of expanding the glob. If it may happen that a glob will not find a match (like `title[.]txt` not finding a `title.txt` file) then you should also set the nullglob shell option to remove the glob (as opposed of leaving it in the command line).

But that is also not portable:

- ksh  : Has no nullglob option. Only works using `echo ~(N)title?(.*).txt`
- bash : `shopt -s nullglob`.
- zsh  : `set -o NULL_GLOB` or `set -G`

Also, if nullglob is set and no pattern is matched, `cp` will generate an error, as cp will "see" this command line:

```
cp  dir/
```

Where no source is given.

### failglob

A similar problem is generated by failglob. If any of several patterns are not matched, the whole command fails.

```
cp title[.]txt title?(.*).txt dir/
```

will fail if any of the two patterns fail.

## Final

The only way to make the cp work even with no match at all and no getting an error from cp, is:

```
$ bash -O nullglob -c '
    set -- title[.]txt title.*.txt
    [ $# -ge 1 ] && cp "$@" dir/
  '

$ ksh -c '
      set -- ~(N)title[.]txt ~(N)title.*.txt
      [ $# -ge 1 ] && cp "$@" dir/
  '
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no equivalent in the standard shell wildcards, but some shells have some extension for that:

#### zsh

in zsh, that's the `#` operator, enabled with the `extendedglob` option:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
cp -- *title(.*)#.txt* dest/
```

You can use EREs or PCREs in globs using the `e` glob qualifier:

```
cp -- *(e['[[ REPLY =~ "title(\..*)*\.txt" ]]']) dest/
```

(issue `set -o rematchpcre` for that to use PCREs instead of EREs, or use `-pcre-match` instead of `=~` after `zmodload zsh/pcre`)

#### ksh

In ksh (all versions), `x*` is `*(x)`:

```
cp -- *title*(.*).txt* dest/
```

#### bash

bash supports the ksh operators with the `extglob` option:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -- *title*(.*).txt* dest/
```

#### ksh93

`ksh93` can use regexps in its globs:

```
cp -- *~(E:title(\..*)*\.txt)* dest/
```

(`E` for **E**xtended regexps here).

It can also convert EREs to glob patterns with:

```
$ printf '%P\n' 'title(\..*)*\.txt'
*title*(\.*)\.txt*
```

(those backslashes are superfluous here though)

Comment: Isn't that original just `title.*.txt title.txt`? (Or some variant with nullglob and the one outlier written as a glob to avoid the possible "File not found" error.)

Comment: In that case yes though that should be `*title.*.txt* *title.txt*` to be functionally equivalent to his `egrep` approach. I suspect they meant something like `^title(\.[^.]+)*\.txt$`. In any case, this answer focuses on the *what's the shell glob equivalent of regexp `*`* question.